# My headphone set doesn't play any sound

Tags: headphones, iphone

After plugging in my headphone into my iphone 4s no sound comes through. I can
hear the music from the phone itself. Do I need to change the settings?

Comment: The answer could be almost anything. Do the headphones work when plugged into other devices? Do the headphones have an integrated microphone? Have you tried raising the volume with the headphones in (both on the headphones, if possible, and on the phone)? Could there be lint in your headphone jack, which sometimes prevents a clean connection? Providing more details will help us answer, but generally you *don't* have to change settings to use headphones. :)

Comment: can you try with different headphones? connect the troublesome headphones to something else? This should at least allow to determine whether the problem lies with the iPhone or the headphones.

Comment: My 4s is going same thing. Went to the apple store and got a different phone. Got home updated it. And this is one is doing the same thing. The head phones are working on my daughters iPhone 4

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue with a 4 and a 3GS, the solution? it was dust, I had to use a pin to get dust out, after that it worked.

If that is not the issue, try using the headphones in another device. Also try using other headphones in the iPhone.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are not pushing it in all the way.  I thought mine were defective until I pushed harder than I thought I should.

If you have any kind of phone protector make sure the jack hole opening is not not obstructed by the cover! You might have to stretch the cover hole a little to push headphone jack all the way in! That was my problem it works fine when in all the way.